# Is there a way to build an apk for android API level 15 in unity 5.6?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

The min level that I can set in unity is API level 16, however, I need to run a game in an old tablet. Is there a way to do it?. If not, which version of unity supports it?

Answer (score 4):

Unity 5.6 dropped support for Android 4.0.x or lower. It only supports Android 4.1 (API Level 16) or higher. See https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements and https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0

Unity 5.5 is the last one to support Android 2.3.1 (API Level 9).